# Troubleshooting DIT FFT Radix-2 Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, math, fft, dft

I have implemented a recursive radix-2 DIT FFT in Java, and a regular DFT to verify my results from the FFT, but the results from the two differ and I cannot seem to figure it out. Both are fed the entire array with the apply()-methods, start and stop index is 0 and data.length respectively. The DFT version looks correct with a nice peak at bin 50 while the FFT one is full of garbage. What am I doing wrong?

This is the FFT implementation (adapted from http://www.engineeringproductivitytools.com/stuff/T0001/PT04.HTM "A Recursive DIT FFT Routine.", I verified by comparing to the pseudo code at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#Pseudocode):

```
public class DITFFT2 extends Transform {
public float[] apply(float[] data, int startIndex, int stopIndex) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    int N;
    float[] filteredData;
    Complex[] complexData;
    Complex[] filteredComplexData;

    if (stopIndex < startIndex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("stopIndex cannot be lower than startIndex!");
    }

    if (stopIndex < 0 || startIndex < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index cannot be negative!");
    }

    N = stopIndex - startIndex;
    filteredData = new float[N];
    complexData = new Complex[N];

    for (int i = startIndex; i < stopIndex; i++) {
        complexData[i-startIndex] = new Complex(data[i], 0.0f);
    }

    filteredComplexData = transform(complexData, N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        filteredData[i] = filteredComplexData[i].abs();
    }

    return filteredData;
}

public Complex[] transform(Complex[] data, int N) {
    Complex x;
    Complex[] result = new Complex[N];

    if (N == 1) {
        result[0] = data[0];
    } else {
        Complex[] fe = new Complex[N/2];
        Complex[] fo = new Complex[N/2];

        for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
            fe[i] = data[2*i];
            fo[i] = data[2*i+1];
        }

        Complex[] Fe = transform(fe, N / 2);
        Complex[] Fo = transform(fo, N / 2);

        for (int k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
            x = Fo[k].copy();
            x.mul(getTwiddleFactor(k, N));

            result[k] = Fe[k].copy();
            result[k].add(x);

            result[k+N/2] = Fe[k].copy();
            result[k+N/2].sub(x);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private Complex getTwiddleFactor(int k, int N) {
    return new Complex(1.0f, (float)(-2.0f * Math.PI * k / (float)N));
}
}
```

And this is the DFT implementation:

```
public class DFT extends Transform {
public float[] apply(float[] data, int startIndex, int stopIndex) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    int N;
    float[] filteredData;
    Complex[] complexData;
    Complex[] filteredComplexData;

    if (stopIndex < startIndex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("stopIndex cannot be lower than startIndex!");
    }

    if (stopIndex < 0 || startIndex < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index cannot be negative!");
    }

    N = stopIndex - startIndex;
    filteredData = new float[N];
    complexData = new Complex[N];
    filteredComplexData = new Complex[N];

    for (int i = startIndex; i < stopIndex; i++) {
        complexData[i-startIndex] = new Complex(data[i], 0.0f);
        filteredComplexData[i-startIndex] = new Complex(0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
            Complex c = complexData[n].copy();
            filteredComplexData[k].add(c.mul(new Complex(1.0f, (float)(-2*Math.PI*n*k/(float)N))));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        filteredData[i] = filteredComplexData[i].abs();
    }

    return filteredData;
}
}
```

Now, both seems to give the correct answer for [8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 0.0], which is [20.0, 4.0j, 12.0, -4.0j]. But if I feed them a sine produced by:

```
mBuffer = new float[1024];
float sampleRate = 1000.0f;
float frequency = 50.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < mBuffer.length; i++) {
    mBuffer[i] = (float)(0.5*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i*frequency/sampleRate));
}
```

The implementation of Complex for reference:

```
public final class Complex {
public float mR, mTheta;

public Complex() {
    mR = 0.0f;
    mTheta = 0.0f;
}

public Complex(float r, float theta) {
    mR = r;
    mTheta = theta;
}

public Complex copy() {
    return new Complex(mR, mTheta);
}

public Complex add(Complex c) {
    float real, imag;
    real = (float)(mR * Math.cos(mTheta) + c.mR * Math.cos(c.mTheta));
    imag = (float)(mR * Math.sin(mTheta) + c.mR * Math.sin(c.mTheta));

    mR = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(real, 2) + Math.pow(imag, 2));

    if (real != 0.0f) {
        mTheta = (float)Math.atan(imag / real);
    } else {
        mTheta = (float)(imag > 0.0f ? Math.PI/2.0f : Math.PI*3.0f/2.0f);
    }
    return this;
}

public Complex sub(Complex c) {
    float real, imag;
    real = (float)(mR * Math.cos(mTheta) - c.mR * Math.cos(c.mTheta));
    imag = (float)(mR * Math.sin(mTheta) - c.mR * Math.sin(c.mTheta));

    mR = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(real, 2) + Math.pow(imag, 2));

    if (real != 0.0f) {
        mTheta = (float)Math.atan(imag / real);
    } else {
        mTheta = (float)(imag > 0.0f ? Math.PI/2.0f : Math.PI*3.0f/2.0f);
    }
    return this;
}

public Complex mul(Complex c) {
    mR = mR * c.mR;
    mTheta = mTheta + c.mTheta;
    return this;
}

public Complex div(Complex c) {
    mR = mR / c.mR;
    mTheta = mTheta - c.mTheta;
    return this;
}

public Complex pow(float exp) {
    mTheta = mTheta * exp;
    mR = (float)Math.pow(mR, exp);
    return this;
}

public float abs() {
    return mR;
}

public float getRealPart() {
    return (float)(mR * Math.cos(mTheta));
}

public float getImagPart() {
    return (float)(mR * Math.sin(mTheta));
}

public String toStringRectangular() {
    float real, imag;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    real = (float)(mR * Math.cos(mTheta));
    imag = (float)(mR * Math.sin(mTheta));

    sb.append(real);
    if (imag >= 0) {
        sb.append(" + ");
    } else {
        sb.append(" - ");
    }
    sb.append(Math.abs(imag));
    sb.append("i");

    return sb.toString();

}

public String toStringExponential() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(mR);
    sb.append(" * e ^ ");
    sb.append(mTheta);
    sb.append("i");

    return sb.toString();

}

public String toString() {
    return toStringExponential() + " [ " + toStringRectangular() + " ] ";
}

public static Complex[] getInitializedArray(int size) {
    Complex[] arr = new Complex[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Complex(0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    return arr;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FFT implementation seems reasonable. However there is an issue with the use of [`Math.atan`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan(double)) (which return a value within the `[-pi/2,pi/2]`, instead of the whole `[-pi,pi]` range) in `Complex`'s `add` and `sub`.

To resolve this issue you should be using:

```
mTheta = (float)Math.atan2(imag, real);
```